# How can I schedule applications to be run in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

On AWS I can run cloud formation scripts to do things like shutdown my computers on weekends, or run EMR jobs.

How would I schedule tasks on google without creating a tiny instance as a task manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, App Engine allows you to use [Cron Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#cron), which basically can be configured for your purpose. But it requires some knowledge of programming languages like Go, PHP, Java or Python.

Answer (score 2):

**method 1:**

how to schedule machines to run only at certain time periods
pls refer to gcloud compute command [start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start) and [stop](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/stop)

then crontab -e add following tasks as you expect to be ,for example :

```
00 06 * * * /usr/bin/gcloud compute instances start instance-1
00 07 * * * /usr/bin/gcloud compute instances stop instance-1
```

**method 2:**

suggest you use google container engine

then crontab -e
add following tasks as you expect to be ,for example :

```
00 06 * * * /usr/bin/gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize instance-group-1 --size=1
00 07 * * * /usr/bin/gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize instance-group-1 --size=0
```

you need to place your task into your vm instance , and create a template instance from the instance you just created, then create an instance group based on that instance template

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to CloudFormation is the Google Cloud Deployment Manager.
They are quite similar.

[More info here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/)

For the record, you can find a mapping of AWS services and GCP services [here](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/map-aws-google-cloud-platform).

Comment: This does not help, how do I schedule machines to run only at certain time periods. I don't see these options in deployment manager.

Comment: Why just do not use Cron Service with personal scripts?